ESmodule issues with Expo eas build
I'm building a React Native app using Expo.
Using node.js and express.
I had some issues aligning my client and server files in terms of ESmodules and eventually I converted all of my .js files to use 'import' instead of 'require()'.
My setup for configuration files is:
package.json :
{
  "name": "test-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "scripts": {
    ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "axios": "^1.6.7",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^10.0.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "expo": "~50.0.15",
    "expo-dev-client": "~3.3.11",
    "expo-router": "^3.4.8",
    "express": "^4.18.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.6",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.4",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "private": true
}

tsconfig.json :
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ES2020",
    "target": "ES2020",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base"
}

metro.config.cjs : (changed from .js to .cjs due to compile errors)
// Learn more https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-metro
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("expo/metro-config");

/** @type {import('expo/metro-config').MetroConfig} */

const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

module.exports = config;

babel.config.cjs : (changed from .js to .cjs due to compile errors)
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
  };
};

eas.json :
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 7.6.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      },
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}

The problem is that it worked when I was separating node.js commonJS from my client side modules, but then when running the app locally on an emulator it started making compile errors so I fixed it, but when building an EAS build I get errors like:
(in gradlew build process on Expo)
Error: Unable to resolve module fs from
/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js: fs could 
not be found within the project or in these directories:1374  
node_modules1375> 1 | const fs = require('fs')1376    |                     
^1377  2 | const path = require('path')1378  3 | const os = 
require('os')1379  4 | const packageJson = require('../package.json')

If I revert it all back to commonJS / modules I will get the same compile errors I had before. So either way I get errors either locally or when building and I'm trying to understand what the overall configuration is.
Do you know what my config is missing / getting wrong so that this workflow succeeds?
Thanks

just for documentation - related github issue (no answer there as well) https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/1854
